# What do you call a legal statement that states a fact rather than stating a rule of conduct or procedure?

Tags: phrase-request, legalese

What do you call a legal statement that states a fact rather than stating a rule of conduct or procedure?

I can't think of a word. Is there any such word? If there's no such word, which words would you use to refer to it in the shortest and most concise way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean something that's determined in court, it would be a **finding of fact**, or just **finding**, as opposed to a conclusion of law or a ruling. Findings often involve more than finding of fact - a jury verdict is a finding, even where it's just *guilty* or *not guilty*. However, they will always be based on questions of fact, to which the law may have been applied. A final decision may include findings and rationales to come to a final conclusion, applying the law to the facts, in a case where one or more judges are acting as finders of fact as well as judges of law.

If it's something that two parties to a case have agreed as a fact, which the court will then presume to be correct as the parties are agreed, that's a **stipulation**.

Answer (score 3):

If it is the parties to a contract or lawsuit agreeing to some fact, it's a "stipulation".

If it is a statement in legislation that such-and-such is considered true, it's a "finding" of the legislature.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a "statutory declaration" if you want to state a fact and want to have it carry some legal weight.

For example, in Australia,

> "A statutory declaration is a written statement which a person swears, affirms or declares to be true in the presence of an authorised witness."

*[NSW statutory declaration form](http://www.jp.nsw.gov.au/justices-of-the-peace/information-for-jps/performing-your-role-as-a-jp/nsw-statutory-declaration)*

Alternatively, it could be an "affidavit":

> An affidavit is a written statement where the contents are sworn or affirmed to be true. [...] Affidavits are used in ​court as evidence.

*[Affidavit](http://www.lawaccess.nsw.gov.au/Pages/representing/lawassist_readingwritinghome_wysk/lawassist_affidavits_wysk/lawassist_affidavits.aspx)*